# How can I make nav bar static and move up a background image/footer?

Tags: html, css

**Q1**

How can I make my navigation bar static?

**Q2**

How can I move up the background picture to ensure there is no white gaps and adjust the height of the background image? I think I have to use `padding` to move up the image and use `height to manipulate the height of the background image`. Is that correct?

**Q3**

How can delete the white gap above my footer text at the bottom of the webpage section 3 contact us?

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Liam Docherty | London Web Developer &amp; GFX designer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

 <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


    <section class="section1">
        <div class="hero"></div>




        <a href= "#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section class="section2" id = "section2">



        <a href = "#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section">

    </section>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

<footer>
    <div class="page">
        <h1 class="footer">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
    </div>
 </footer>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }
    section {
      position: relative;
    }
    .section1 {
      height: 90vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    .section2 {
      height: 95vh;
      background-color: #A59E8C;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .contact_section {
      height: 93vh;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    footer {
      height: 5vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      text-align: center;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0:
    }
    h1{
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use the `navbar-fixed-top` class provided by Bootstrap to fix the navbar in place.

2) Change the height property of the `section1` class.

3) Create a new section, reduce the height, and remove margin/padding from your h1 class (you had a typo in your CSS, `.footer` not `footer`).

Result:
https://jsfiddle.net/vnkevsnt/8/

Comment: Thanks for the help, for Q2 if I change the height it will change everything within section 1. I only want to change the background image height not the whole section. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe try changing the `background-size` and `background-position` properties in the `section1` class. If you want to move the image up, try `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `position:fixed` to your `.navbar.navbar-default` to fix it. Also be sure to add `width:100%` to make it full width.

(Have a look at [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)) - Bootstrap probably can position with a class but I'm not sure.

Regarding the white space at the bottom, I would personally remove the `height:5vh` from the footer and also add `margin:0` to the H1 element.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has `nav-fixed` class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  ....
</nav>
```

Sample: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/